# How to do multiple inheritance from different classes in python using super()?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Lets say we have different kind of people, pianist,programmer and multitalented person.
so, How do i inherit like this? currently this code gives error Multitalented has no attribute canplaypiano.

```
class Pianist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canplaypiano=True

class Programer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canprogram=True

class Multitalented(Pianist,Programer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.canswim=True
        super(Pianist,self).__init__()
        super(Programer,self).__init__()

Raju=Multitalented()

print(Raju.canswim)
print(Raju.canprogram)
print(Raju.canplaypiano)
```

Also Please mention some well written article about python inheritance/super() i couldnt find a perfect article with clear explaination. thankyou.

Comment: Either use ``Pianist.__init__(self)`` or ``super().__init__()``. Do not mix explicit and super references to the base classes. Note that either *all* or *no* classes in the inheritance hierarchy should use ``super``.

Comment: You are fundamentally misunderstanding how the arguments to `super` work. Read the following: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ there is also a corresponding video presentation from PyCon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: And perhaps, [this example of how you would implement a basic `super` in pure Python might help](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/0d4d2d489347777bc21f9e150149b093)

Answer (score 2):

*All* classes involved in cooperative multiple inheritance need to use `super`, even if the *static* base class is just `object`.

```
class Pianist:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canplaypiano=True

class Programer:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canprogram=True

class Multitalented(Pianist,Programer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canswim=True
        
Raju=Multitalented()

print(Raju.canswim)
print(Raju.canprogram)
print(Raju.canplaypiano)
```

The order in which the initializers run is determined by the method resolution order for `Multitalented`, which you can affect by changing the order in which `Multitalented` lists its base classes.

The first, if not best, article to read is Raymond Hettinger's [Python's `super()` Considered Super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), which also includes advice on how to adapt classes the *don't* themselves use `super` for use in a cooperative multiple-inheritance hierarchy, as well as advice on how to override a function that uses `super` (in short, you can't change the signature).

Answer (score 0):

Dont call `super` with explicit parent classes. In modern python versions (don't know exactly since which version) you call `super` without parameters. That is, in you case you should have had only one line, not two:

```
super().__init__()
```

In somewhat older versions you need to provide the class explicitly, however you should provide the class of "current" object, and the `super` function takes care of finding out the parent classes. In you case it should be:

```
super(Multitalented, self).__init__()
```

Comment: "(don't know exactly since which version)" [Since Python 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/)

Comment: You can still call it with explicit arguments (and in some rare cases it's *necessary*). Python 3 simply added enough compiler magic to provide the correct "defaults" in the usual case.